# Xamarin forms how to log in with Apple account

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I'm trying to publish my first xamarin forms app on IOS. I barred the issue of login with the Apple account.

I have 4 questions, please.

1- If I implement Sign in with Apple only for IOS 13+ will it be accepted? :(

2- I'm trying to use Xamarin Essentials to log in to IOS 13+ as shown in this article:

[Xamarin Essentials](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/authentication-xamarin-essentials-aspnet/)

```
    // Use Native Apple Sign In API's
    r = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync();
```

But I only get back the idToken. AccessToken, name and mail return null. Am I missing something?

3 - And finally I tried to use the plugin.firebaseAuth version 4.0.0-pre01:

[Link plugin](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth)

// For iOS
var credential = CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", idToken, rawNonce: rawNonce);
var result = await CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.Instance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);

// For Android
var provider = new OAuthProvider("apple.com");
var result = await CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.Instance.SignInWithProviderAsync(provider);

It provides an example using prism to deal with this, but when I install the plugin in this version the application is no more than a splash screen and closes, without showing an error in the output.  What am I doing wrong? :(

The first link seems promising for iOS less than 13 and Android using Asp.NET. However in the application I use only the Firebase ClouFirestone and Firebase Hosting for the Administrative Panel. Is it possible for me to sign in Apple without the services of a different backend?

I am very grateful for any light on the path I must follow

Comment: Sign In with Apple is for all new applications on iOS 13 that use third-party authentication services.Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/sign-in-with-apple/android-ios-sign-in

Comment: Hi Lucas! thanks, so for now I don't have to worry about 12-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- If I implement Sign in with Apple only for IOS 13+ will it be accepted?

- It depends, if they don't find any other issues or violation, it will get accepted.

2- I'm trying to use Xamarin Essentials to log in to IOS 13+ as shown in this article: But I only get back the idToken.

- Apple will only provide you the requested details on the first authentication. After that first authentication, you will only get the User Id so be sure to store the details that first time in case you need them.
- This feature needs to be tested on a physical device running iOS 13. The simulator is not reliable, it doesn’t always work properly.
- Should follow the design guidelines when implementing Apple Sign In. You can find it here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/